# Google Analytics : How to track image/PDF URL is accessed?

Tags: google-analytics

I am sending an marketing Email attaching an image or PDF URL.

Is there is any way to track how may users viewed/clicked this page via google analytics ? I could see the number of page view who accessed html pages but seeking for a way to find how many of them accessed image or PDF URL?

Answer (score 0):

Including a link directly to a pdf or image will simply open the resource without JavaScript tracking or cookies required for Google Analytics.
You would need to send a GA hit from your server in response to the request for those files - neither trivial nor recommended in this case

Rather send the link to a page on your site containing the content.
Tracking that in GA is trivial and is likely already set up on your site.

If you need to have the content in a PDF rather than on the web page directly, have a link to the PDF and track that as an [event](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012044?hl=en) or [Virtual Page View](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)

I would also recommend tagging the link in your email with [GA UTM Campaign Parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) to identify the traffic from that link

If your question is about tracking the email itself, please restate the question.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, its not about tracking the email, Campaigns are being sent through Mailchimp and am getting the tracks. But I would like to get the tracks of how many times the link is accessed.

Comment: In that case, have the link point to a page on your site where you feature the pdf.

Comment: In that case, have the link point to a page on your site where you feature the pdf. GA will track that page.
To know that the page views came from the email vs any other route to that page, one needs to use GA UTM Campaign Parameters. 
Without parameters, most visits from that link will appear as direct and inflate your (direct) / (none) metrics.
This would need to be done independently of any email tracking you get in Mailchimp